# Is the scenario described is memory leak or browser issue

Tags: javascript, memory, browser, setinterval

The codes I am testing with:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="xxx"></div>
<script>
var foo = function(){
  this.x = window.localStorage;
  this.y = document.getElementById('xxx');

  this.y.textContent = 'x:' + this.x.length + '-' + Math.random();
}
setInterval(foo, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Image below is memory usage from Chrome
[image: Memory usage from chrome]
Image below is memory usage from Safari
[image: Memory usage from safari]

Is it because the way I use setInterval is causing memory leaks? and Chrome is just smart enough to garbage collect, but Safari is having issues?

What I am actually doing is just using setInterval to periodically get data via ajax and write to localStorage. At first I thought I am using setInterval in a bad way, but after stripping down everything and just run the sample code above, Safari will still takes up memory and not releasing it.

Comment: Isn't `this` going to be the same as `window` in this context? (not that I believe that's what's causing the leak)

Comment: yes, `this` is also in window context, I have tried `var x, y` but the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its memory leak. You create js object linked with DOM element in global scope.

Comment: Let say I need to fix it for this instance, how should I change my codes? Thanks..